# What is contextual sessions in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

1. What is contextual session in Hibernate?
2. When I created and closed a sessions in between use contextual session implementation interfaces?

Answer (score 9):

Think of Hibernate's `Contextual Session` as a mapping of a current Session to a user's Context.

For example: a single transaction could be such a context, hence if the Hibernate Session's lifecycle matches a life of this transaction, the Session could be called contextual, where a single transaction defines such a `context`. Sometimes this particular case is labeled as a `session-per-request` model.

A Hibernate interface [CurrentSessionContext](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/context/spi/CurrentSessionContext.html) is there to map a current session ( e.g. `SessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` ) to different contexts. This interface has 3 implementations:

- [JTASessionContext](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/context/internal/JTASessionContext.html): current sessions are tracked and scoped by a JTA transaction. The processing here is exactly the same as in the older JTA-only approach. See the Javadocs for details.
- [ThreadLocalSessionContext](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/context/internal/ThreadLocalSessionContext.html): current sessions are tracked by thread of execution. See the Javadocs for details.
- [ManagedSessionContext](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/context/internal/ManagedSessionContext.html): current sessions are tracked by thread of execution. However, you are responsible to bind and unbind a Session instance with static methods on this class: it does not open, flush, or close a Session

Take a look at the [Architecture Current Session](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#architecture-current-session) part of the Hibernate documentation for more "official" details.

Comment: you should link to the official api doc, and to the latest reference manual.

Answer (score 1):

Another very good link explaining the concept of Hibernate Contextual Session

http://relation.to/2037.lace