# HibernateTemplate support in Hibernate 4 not working

Tags: spring, hibernate

We were using Spring HibernateTemplate with Hibernate

The HibernateTemplate was created by reading the Hibernate.cfg file

```
SessionFactory sf = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure
("/com/examscripts/exam.hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
HibernateTemplate ht = new HibernateTemplate(sf);
```

The Hibernate.cfg contains a Datasource in weblogic which is pointing to mySql

```
<session-factory>
    <property name="connection.datasource">MYSQLDS</property>
    <property name="default_schema">examSch</property>
</session-factory>
```

After moving to Hibernate 4.x I found that I cannot use HibernateTemplate

So I used the SessionFactory directly - but it started giving an error :

> org.hibernate.HibernateException: No CurrentSessionContext configured!

I am getting this exception when I am doing this :

```
Session session = sf.getCurrentSession();
```

I am puzzled - so in Hibernate 3.x with spring hibernate template I did not get such an exception -

so why am I getting it in 4.x

Was HibernateTemplate taking care of this ?

I also read that now in my cfg.xml i will need to provide :

```
<property key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">jta</property>
```

Should it be jta or thread ?

I am assuming jta since I am using datasource from weblogic - is that correct ?

NOTE - tried reading :
http://relation.to/2037.lace

[Spring Transactions and hibernate.current_session_context_class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18832889/spring-transactions-and-hibernate-current-session-context-class)

[What is contextual sessions in hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7871386/what-is-contextual-sessions-in-hibernate)

[using current_session_context_class property hibernate 3 hibernate 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19875485/using-current-session-context-class-property-hibernate-3-hibernate-4)

BUT I am a noob - it made no sense to me :(

EDIT / UPDATE 1

I made the following entry in my hibernate.cfg file:

Changed it to:

```
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
```

Exception:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: createQuery is not valid without active transaction
```

at the line:

```
Session session = getSessionFactoryCustom().getSessionFactoryTest().getCurrentSession();
List<Person> personList = session.createQuery("from Person").list(); // exception is here
```

Then I tried changing it to :

```
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">SpringCurrentContext</property>
```

Now the exception is :

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No CurrentSessionContext configured!
```

at line:

```
Session session = SessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
```

Then I tried changing it to :

```
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">jta</property>
```

Now the exception is :

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No TransactionManagerLookup specified
    at org.hibernate.context.internal.JTASessionContext.currentSession(JTASessionContext.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1014)
    at com.mkyong.common.dao.TestDaoImpl.list(TestDaoImpl.java:56)
```

TestDaoImpl at line 56:

> Session session = SessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

So now which TransactionManagerLookup should I specify ?

Does anyone have a working example of their hibernate.cfg with the necessary configurations that will work with weblogic datasource ?

Comment: Few questions - What error do you get when you use hibernate template? What is your spring library version? Post the exact code that fails to narrow down the issue.

Comment: This is the error I get : Got the following exception:
Exception in thread "Report Generator Thread" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/hibernateSessionFactory.openSession()                           Lorg/hibernate/classic/Session;
At the following line of code :
List myList=templ.findByCriteria(subSelectCriteria, 0, 10);

I opened up hibernate-core-4.3.4.Final.jar - and it has no org.hibernate.classic.Session 
this is present in 3.x version of hibernate while hibernate 4.x has org.hibernate.SessionFactory - this is what I think is breaking the usage of HibernateTemplate - am using Spring 4.0.4

Comment: Why aren't you simply using Spring to configure the session factory but are doing that yourself? Next to that the thread context should be the `SpringCurrentContext` fqn unless you are using JTA.

Comment: ok thanks - I do not have more than 1 database - so I do not need JTA right ? - so the property should be set to : <property key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">SpringCurrentContext </property> - is that correct ?